# Can I move a clients website from yahoo hosting to godaddy hosting without losing google page rankings?

Tags: google, web-hosting, ranking

I have a client who wants to switch hosting from yahoo to godaddy and utilize wordpress to run site.  Can I move a clients website from yahoo hosting to godaddy hosting without losing google page rankings?

Comment: I'm pretty sure google page rankings depend on the URL, not on the server where the URL is hosted, and I assume you'll be using the same URL?

Comment: @barrycarter Network neighborhoods do matter a lot. Chose a low quality host and you will see what I mean. Or if you are on a shared server and a site becomes compromised. The IP address, IP address block, the company, the region/country, all can effect a sites performance.

Comment: In this case, as long as the requirements for your site is there, there should be no difference between Yahoo! and Google and rank will not be effected.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of discussion about wether the IP address can affect the page rank or not. For example here: https://pressable.com/blog/2013/02/21/do-you-need-a-dedicated-ip-address-for-seo/ and here https://wpengine.com/blog/the-myth-of-the-dedicated-ip-address-for-seo/

The **short answer is yes** it can affect your page rank